# Fast script to cut section of logfile based on timestamp

Tags: log-files, scripting

I am looking for a **fast script** that will parse a large mail.log, and return the portion *between two specified timestamps*.   I would like to run it on all of my mailservers, and have them copy the relevent log portions to a central location for further analysis.

I have written something in bash that works, but is slow.

Does anybody know of **anything that already exists** to accomplish this - or do I need to learn perl and make something up myself?

(I am not putting this on SO, as I am not yet at the point where I want to *write* any code - just looking for something somebody else is already using)

Answer (score 7):

I love awk :)

For my logs, which are in the format:

```
Jul 14 12:49:10 xxxxxx sendmail[31337]: ...........
```

I would use:

```
awk '$3 >= "12:00:00" && $3 <= "13:00:00" {print;}' < /var/log/maillog
```

Presumably you can adapt that as necessary, for instance if you don't split logs by day.

**Bonus:**

Apache format, which I happen to have kicking around:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [01/Jul/2009:03:06:24 -0400] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3638
awk '$4 >= "[01/Jul/2009:03:00:00" && $4 <= "[01/Jul/2009:04:00:00" {print;}' < access_log
```

Answer (score 0):

**For a specific day range and to print > output-file**

*(I can not put as a comment in the above answer otherwise I will have done that)*

HTH

```
awk '$2 >= "21" && $3 >= "09:00:00" && $2 >= "21" && $3 <= "11:00:10" {print > "m_range.log";}' < /var/log/m.log

cat m_range.log 
...
Nov 21 09:00:17 mail postfix/qmgr[1694]: 1C50D276524A: from=<www-data@...ia.com>, size=2378, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
...
```