# Grep date with regex

Tags: unix, log-files, grep, regex

I have files with lines in the following formats:

```
.
.
.
12/16/09 17:56:30.211 rest of line...
.
.
.
12/17/09 05:34:10.809 rest of line...
.
.
```

How do I grep the lines out of this file that are between two dates, i.e. all the values for one day?  I need to create a daily file with the contents from all the different server logs for that day.

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/40681/fast-script-to-cut-section-of-logfile-based-on-timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brackets can be used to give you a range of numbers.  The carrot can match the start of a line.  So..

`grep "^12\/1[6-8]\/09"` will give you everything that starts with 12/16/09, 12/17/09, and 12/18/09

Comment: Thanks, I was so hung up on the timestamp that I didn't think of just using the day.

Comment: You could add a space after the year also, like `grep "^12\/1[6-8]\/09 "` to be sure.